# Seeking Colombia municipality geometries

Tags: openstreetmap, data, gadm, colombia

I'm looking for shapefiles (or some similar format) of Colombia's municipality boundaries.

[Wikipedia has a map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mapa_de_Colombia_(municipios).svg) that seems to be correct and which matches another dataset that I will eventually be merging in based on municipality names and DANE codes. I've tried contacting the file creator about the underlying source data, but without success.

I've tried **GADM**, but some of the municipalities are missing/incorrect, e.g. all the way in the South Amazons should have 11 municipalities, not 8.

[image]

Here's **OpenStreeMap** with data export via [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/). Many municipalities are simply just missing, although the borders for those that are there appear to be correct and more detailed than GADM.

[image]

I guess I could try to combine departments that OpenStreeMap had all municipalities for with the GADM data, but it looks like that would still only partially get me there. And in general it just makes me a bit suspicious about using the GADM data at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the WFS or WMS servers of the Instituto Geográfico Agustín Codazzi (here:http://www.igac.gov.co/wps/portal/igac/raiz/iniciohome/MapasdeColombia/Descargas).

These services have different layers for geodesic features and demographics.

If that doesn't work, you can check this link with the shapefile I use for Colombian municipalities: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i0ao837gj5wpkic/AAAnzZf-tJIKUmZvTKrvXPMpa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else serves you, here are a set of examples you create visualizing the municipalities of Colombia from a geojson file that I managed to achieve

https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/727e8992e9599b9d9f1dbfdc4c8e479e

If you look at my bl.ocks.org/john-warra you can see more examples, but stackexchange will not let me upload more than two links

And here's a react component you create to make it easy to create these maps

https://github.com/john-guerra/ColombiaVisualizationReact

Answer (score 1):

Colombia's National Administrative Department of Statistics hosts shapefiles that have official municipality boundaries here: https://geoportal.dane.gov.co/?descarga-marco-geoestadistico-nacional

Also, as of today, GADM is still missing municipalities in Amazonas, and in the OpenStreetMap data, some municipal boundaries intersect their neighbors.

Edit: Possibly this link is nicer (the CSS on the first link isn't great for some browsers/viewport sizes): https://geoportal.dane.gov.co/metadatos/descarga_mgn/

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect (one note, doesn't seem to work on Safari).

Comment: @andybega True, plus the bottom row of the table was cut off on Chrome for me. The interesting part of that page is loaded in an iframe. I edited in the link to the iframe's source. It works for me on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Districts/Boroughs in Bogotá are called *Localidades*. You can download them from the
*Infraestructura de Datos Espaciales para el Distrito Capital* * (IDECA) [website](https://www.ideca.gov.co/), specifically [here](https://www.ideca.gov.co/recursos/mapas/localidad-bogota-dc).

In the case of Medellín, these are called *Comunas* and can be found on the map catalogue's webpage from the town/municipal hall, specifically [here](https://www.medellin.gov.co/geonetwork/srv/spa/catalog.search#/metadata/27e73f95-b2e8-4519-8644-6345a65bc0f5).

<sup>* Roughly translates to Spatial Data Infraestrcuture for the Capital District.</sup>